# Verification email is not showing up in my inbox

Tags: support, new-users, email, accounts

When I opened my settings on Stack Overflow, I typed in the email that I wanted to change to, and after I clicked on the "send verification email" button, nothing shows up in my inbox.

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try checking your spam folder? DId you try waiting longer?

Comment: Have you double-checked the email address? Is it a popular email provider, or a single-use email?

Comment: I've tried both double-checking, and also waited for a very long period of time, but still no email showed up.

Comment: Hi, so I just tried making an account with the email I wanted to change this account to, but when it said to check my inbox for an account verification, nothing shows up. Do you think that this is a problem with Stack Overflow, or my email?

Answer (score -3):

- Check the email address that you've entered.
- If the email is correct then check your spam folder.
- If the spam folder doesn't contain your verification email, then delete some unimportant emails.
- If that also doesn't work then wait a little longer for your verification email.

***If nothing works, then go for help center.***

Comment: *"If the spam folder doesn't contain your verification email, then delete some unimportant emails."* -- how does that help?

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine My guess is that deleting some unimportant emails is to free up some space if your inbox is full, although unlikely these days